# ValueError: SymbolicConstant name ' ' may only contain upper case, digit or underscore

Tags: python, valueerror

I'm trying to restart previous job using abaqus in ubuntu, but following error occurs. The same job and python code worked well in window os. How could I fix it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SMAPylModules/SMAPylDriverPy.m/src/analysis.py", line 1704, in <module>
  File "SMAPylModules/SMAPylDriverPy.m/src/analysis.py", line 1458, in run
  File "SMAPylModules/SMAPylDriverPy.m/src/analysis.py", line 652, in _scanRestartOrImport
  File "SMAPylModules/SMAPylDriverPy.m/src/driverOdbScan.py", line 18, in scan
  File "SMAPylModules/SMAPylDriverPy.m/src/odbPyAccess.py", line 143, in __init__
  File "SMAPylModules/SMAPylDriverPy.m/src/odbPyAccess.py", line 95, in __init__
  File "SMAPylModules/SMAPylDriverPy.m/src/symbolicConstants.py", line 92, in __new__
ValueError: SymbolicConstant name '' may only contain upper case, digit or underscore
```

Comment: Can you please provide us a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: I think you are using space between the words of that 'Symbolic Constant'. It would be better if you share those lines of code which throwing the error